# Injecting mock presenters using Dagger2

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-instrumentation

My goal is to write instrumentation tests where the class under test is an Activity which has a mock presenter injected into it. I'd also like the presenter to have the same life as the activity that holds it. Finally, the mocks presenter that gets injected in the activity should also be able to be referenced from the test class so that the mock can be setup, verified etc... as part of the test.

Project setup:

I'm using gradle flavors to break the project into source sets that can be used for the different types of tests I'm trying to write. I have a mockRepo flavor where I have Dagger components and modules that create a "real" instance of all of my dependencies except for my repositories which I mock. I have an endToEnd flavor where I inject real instances of every dependency. The last flavor I'm attempting to add is a mockPresenter flavor which creates mock instances of the presenters so that I can truly isolate my views and ensure that when an activity's lifecycle methods run that the correct methods are called on the presenter.

The mockRepo and endToEnd flavors were pretty straightforward to write because in both cases I was able to extend the application class for testing and was able to swap out different dagger components in the application class which made it very easy to inject a mock repository.

The mockPresenter flavor is giving me problems. The issue is that I'm unable to inject a mock presenter into MainActivity without adding a method like

```
DaggerMainComponent getMainComponent() {
    return mDaggerMainComponent
}
```

to my application class. I'd prefer not to do that because it seems like the application class shouldn't need to know about DaggerMainComponent at all and it's just a workaround.

Here's how the injection code for MainActivity currently looks:

```
@Inject
MainContract.Presenter mMainPresenter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mMainComponent = DaggerMainComponent
            .builder()
            .appInjector(((MyApplication) getApplicationContext()).getAppComponent())
            .mainModule(new MainModule())
            .mainPresenterModule(new MainPresenterModule())
            .build();
    mMainComponent.inject(this);

    mMainPresenter.setView(this);
}
```

What I like about doing things this way is that in onCreate I used the Dagger generated class called DaggerMainComponent to create an instance of component which guarantees that I will get a new Component which guarantees that I will get a new presenter every time onCreate runs. Also, I can get a reference to the component in onCreate and dereference it in onDestroy(). However, it also seems that it isn't possible to inject a mock MainPresenter because the only chance I have to do that is this here:

```
.mainPresenterModule(new MainPresenterModule())
```

MainPresenterModule only creates "real" instances of the presenter and if I were so use something like:

```
.mainPresenterModule(new MockPresenterModule())
```

then there would be no way to use a "real" version of the presenter for the production version of the app.

The workarounds that I've seen for this situation all seem to involve having a method on the application class that either return a component or a module. In the production version of the app the application class would return either a component that depends on modules that provide real instances or could even just supply the module itself. The test version of the app would have a test application that would extend the production application class and override some of the methods so when the test application was running it would return either the mock version of the component which would declare modules that would supply mocks or it would return the mock modules directly.

The other workaround I've seen uses an @ExposedForTesting annotation in the application class which seems like something I'd like to avoid.

Having the application class expose getter methods so that mock / real dependencies can be injected seems like a code smell to me because I can't see a real reason that the application class should know about the dependencies that should be injected into MainActivity. Also, it seems like you'd end up with one getter method per Activity or Fragment which would start to bloat the application class.

Is there a way to inject mocks into an Activity so that the application class doesn't play such a big part in providing the correct modules or components?

Comment: Just my opinion: I don't see how a different application is that bad... It's just some getters...

Comment: @LeandroBorgesFerreira It just seems like a weird thing to have to do so I am questioning if I'm missing some bigger concept in Dagger2 that would allow me to do what I want without relying on the Application class to help route modules / components to the correct activities / fragments.

Comment: This!!!m Ive been hoping someone should have solved this by now!. Please..sensei, tell me you have found a workaround.

Comment: @yUdoDis I never figured this out.

Comment: @neonDion T_T thank you for suffering with me, so is it not possible or is it not supported what you think?